# Mostar imagen en picturebox segun criterio de busqueda

Tags: c#, directorioactivo

```
 public void ShowAssistanceInfo(string Name, string EmployeeNO)
    {
        try
        {
            string Path = "ruta donde estan las imagenes";

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path, EmployeeNO + "*.jpg");

            if (filePaths.Length > 0 )
            {
                picBox.ImageLocation = filePaths[0].ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" ERROR!!!! Form=" + this.Name + " , Method = " + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ", Error Message = " + exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

El codigo anterior se usa para mostrar imagenes en un picturebox de acuerdo a lo que diga en un textbox, se esta usando **Active Directory** para obtener información de usuarios, lo que se hace es lo siguiente:

[image]

Al digitar 1111 debera cargar la imagen del empleado 1111 asi como su info en la zona AD User Info (la imagen esta en una ruta del equipo guardada como el numero del empleado es decir 1111.jpg), al digitar pperez que es el empleado 1111 deberá de igual manera poder verse su info y foto y si se digita Pedro Perez igual!

Solo se ha logrado la parte de la foto cuando se digita el numero de empleado se quiere lograr de las otras 2 formas que se mencionan pero no se ha dado con la solución.

Además cuando se busca un usuario que ya no exista en AD o que esté disable se muestra un message box indicando que el usuario no se encontró, hasta ahi todo bien, pero si la imagen de ese usuario existe en la ruta de imágenes se carga la imagen del mismo aunque su info no se muestre y se haya mostrado el messagebox.

Como se podrían solucionar estos problemas?

PD: De ser necesario alguna otra parte del código para poder brindar algún tipo de ayuda me lo hacen saber, muchas gracias

Este código es el que se tiene para capturar la info de AD y luego mostrarla en el form:

```
private void ShowUserInfo()  /*esto nos va a servir mostrar la info de los usuarios en base a si se busca por username o employeeID 
                                                            y si no existe en AD simplemente dice que no se encontro*/
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            pnlBlock.BringToFront();
            pnlBlock.Visible = true;

            SearchResult SR = null;

            if (txtSearchUser.Text.Trim().IndexOf("0") >= 0)
                SR = BusqPorEmployNum(GetDirectorySearcher(), txtSearchUser.Text.Trim());
            else
                SR = BusqPorUserName(GetDirectorySearcher(), txtSearchUser.Text.Trim());

            if (SR != null)
                GetUserInfo(SR);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("User Not Found, Try again!", "Search Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        private void GetUserInfo(SearchResult SR) // obtiene la info de los usuarios de AD y los carga a los label 
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            pnlBlock.Visible = false;

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
                lblUsername.Text = "Username : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value != null)
                lblName.Text = "First Name : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["initials"].Value != null)
                lblMidName.Text = "Middle Name : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["initials"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value != null)
                lblLastName.Text = "Last Name : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value != null)
                lblEmail.Text = "Email ID : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["title"].Value != null)
                lblTitle.Text = "Title : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["title"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value != null)
                lblCompany.Text = "Company : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["l"].Value != null)
                lblCity.Text = "City : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["l"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeNumber"].Value != null)
                lblEmplNum.Text = "Employee Number : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeNumber"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["co"].Value != null)
                lblCountry.Text = "Country : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["co"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["postalCode"].Value != null)
                lblPostcod.Text = "Postal Code : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["postalCode"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null)
                lblTelef.Text = "Telephone No. : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();

            if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["uidNumber"].Value != null)
                lblUid.Text = "Batch Number : " + SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["uidNumber"].Value.ToString();

        }
```

Además en la siguiente imagen que adjunto intento ser lo más detallado posible con respecto a mi duda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No importa que se introduzca en el buscador (como ejemplífico en la imagen) la imagen siempre debe aparacer porque la imagen se guarda en la carpeta que mencioné al principio de mi duda por el numero de empleado, es decir que si busco a 0001, pperez o Pedro Perez siempre debe aparecer la imagen porque siempre deberé compararla con el numero de empleado de lo que se esté buscando, además me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para evitar que aparezca la imagen de un numero de empleado que no aparezca en AD esto porque ya lo hemos hecho con el código que tenemos y si la imagen existe en la ruta siempre se muestra aunque no exista en AD

Comment: La imagen no deberías mostrarla a partir de la información introducida por el usuario, si no a partir de la información recuperada del AD. De esta forma siempre tendrías el nº de empleado.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva hola y gracias por tu respuesta y como podría hacer para lograr eso y poder seguir obteniendo la imagen sin importar si busco el username, nombre o numero de empleado? Lo pregunto porque es la primer vez que se trabaja con AD y se nos está complicando un poco porque mi compañero y yo somos algo novatos en esta área!

Agradezco cualquier respuesta que nos puedas dar, que pases lindo día

Comment: Pero ¿tienes ya el código que recupera la información del usuario del AD y la muestra en el formulario? Estaría bien que lo incluyeras en la pregunta.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva es correcto, el código que trae y muestra la info del usuario de AD ya se encuentra hecho, la información se muestra en la sección que dice "AD User Info"

En este momento no tengo a mano el código que te menciono ya que, no lo tengo en mi PC apenas lo tenga a mano te lo muestro y te lo hago saber para ver si nos puedes ayudar o aconsejar un poco más y así poder salir de ese dilema. 

Agradecemos toda la ayuda que nos puedas brindar, que estés bien

Comment: @AsierVillanueva hola amigo, espero estés muy bien y te deso un muy buen inicio de semana, dejo adjunto el código que me pediste y espero sea posible que se pueda brindar algún tipo de ayuda o consejo

Comment: Por lo que estas diciendo, en realidad no tenes ningun problema con tu codigo (encuentras las imagenes, las puedes cargar) si no un problema con tu logica de ejecucion. Hay algun problema especifico en la carga o es solo el problema de que hace cosas que no deberia hacer?

Comment: @gbianchi hola amigo y gracias es correcto, es más que nada a la hora de querer hacer lo mismo pero cuando buscas por username y que se muestre la imagen, porque si buscas por numero de empleado la misma aparece pero si es por username no.

Y si buscas un numero de empleado que no exista en AD pero si exista en la imagen en la carpeta su info no se muestra pero su imagen si y eso es lo que no se quiere

Comment: Entonces vas a tener que mostrar y explicar la logica, para que podamos decirte donde esta el problema logico que tiene tu codigo. Como decis anda todo, por lo que decirte donde esta el problema es bastante confuso en este momento. A grandes rasgos no es un problema de programacion de por si, si no un problema de como estructuraste tu codigo. Tal vez con ver las cabeceras de las funciones y que hace cada una, mas el orden de llamada podamos ordenarlo.

Comment: Revertí lo de "solucionado", pues eso queda indicado al aceptar la respuesta. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui muchas gracias, perdón eso no lo sabía!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que no aparece en tu código es la llamada al método `ShowAssistanceInfo` que carga la imagen.

Entiendo que deberías hacerlo en el propio método `GetUserInfo` que se encarga de rellenar la información del usuario en el formulario. Al igual que da valor a los labels debería hacerlo con la imagen.

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
if (SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeNumber"].Value != null)
    var employNumber = SR.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeNumber"].Value.ToString();
    lblEmplNum.Text = "Employee Number : " + employNumber;
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(image_folder_path, $"{employNumber}.jpg")){
        picBox.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(image_folder_path, $"{employNumber}.jpg");
    }
    else{
        picBox.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(image_folder_path, "noImage.jpg");
    }
}
else{
    picBox.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(image_folder_path, "noImage.jpg");
}
```

Al recuperar el nº de empleado, se comprueba si existe el fichero de imagen y se carga en el `PictureBox`. Si no existe el fichero o el nº de empleado no tiene valor se carga una imagen por defecto.

Comment: Listo, Asier! Funciona Excelente, muchisimas gracias!